# Is it good to use tokens for a Quiz system?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

In my quiz system a teacher can create a range of dates and times for a quiz and student can participate the quiz in this range. But teacher also will create a total time for each quiz so students have to end their quizes in this time at the given date and time range(for example 02.15.2021-10:00 and 02.15.2021-15:00 is range and 15 minutes is total time). Arranging this range is easy but for total time, i am thinking of using tokens. When a student starts a quiz given 15 total minutes, i give the student a token with 15 min expiration time(from when quiz starts). And this way i can control the due time. Do you think this is feasable way to do this or do you suggest something else?

Note:thinking json web tokens to do this.

Comment: I don’t see how tokens would be useful, you already need to have some data storage for the quiz so why not just store the start time and then you definitely know when it ends? And you can do much more useful reporting to the user than just expiring authorization or something else

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i tought about using database for this, but isn't this effect database performance? because i will record the answer evertime someone answer a question, not just end of the exam. Do you think continuous queries to the database is better than using tokens?

Comment: Databases usually can handle billions of records, so unless you have very limited resources or a huge number of concurrent users it shouldn’t be a problem

Comment: I think using database is better for this, i ll go with it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need the server to keep the state of the quiz. You wouldn't want a student to be able to go back to the quiz URI a couple of hours later with a modified token and pass the quiz. There needs to be a record on the server that gets persisted to some storage that records the fact that a specific user has started a specific quiz at a specific time. You could identify the specific quiz instance as a GUID (`Guid.NewGuid`) when starting the quiz for the student. You'd also have to store the user id of the student which needs to be authenticated somehow and you'd record the start time for the quiz. When the user submits the quiz to be graded, they need to provide the GUID. Again, this all assumes that you have correctly authenticated a user.

Comment: They can't change the token because once a json web token modified without my secret key it won't be usable.  I was thinking of keep the starting time at the token and verify every time a student answer a question. But as Sami Kuhmonen said i think it would be better to keep this record in database and verify student's due time with a database query. I tought this would be a burden for database performance but as he mentioned databases can handle this. What do you think?
note: i am correctly authenticating the users with access and refresh tokens

Comment: Sami Kuhmomen is correct. You could certainly make tokens work, but it is 300 or 400% more effort that doing it as he and I am suggesting and in the end.